# multiple accept values in request for wiremock

Tags: json, http-headers, wiremock

I'm attempting to write a mock for my api.

To test it correctly I need a request whick allows application/json and */* to be accepted.
Which sould work in HTML like this

```
application/json, */*
```

When I use this in my wiremock mapping json file, i recieve errors, or with minor changes just "not matching" response.

My Json is build like this

```
"request": {
    "urlPathPattern": "/publish",
    "method": "POST",
    "headers": {
        "Accept": {
            "contains": "application/json, */*"
        }
    },
    "bodyPatterns": []
}
```

I couldn't find any solution, neither on the wiremock docs nor with the help of google, but maybe my description of the problem was just not showing the results I would have needed.

Can anyone enlighten me?
with best regards

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your problem, you need to accept both `application/json` and `*/*` as Accept header values. I'm assuming that the case where you'd receive something matching `*/*` would interpret those `*` as wildcards, so `some/type` would match. In this case, you just want to make sure that the Accept header has *some value*.

If that is the case, I'd recommend you use `matches` to do regex matching on the header.

```
"request": {
    "urlPathPattern": "/publish",
    "method": "POST",
    "headers": {
        "Accept": {
            "matches": ".*\/.*"
        }
    },
    "bodyPatterns": []
}
```

If you instead need to match exactly on either `application/json` or `*/*`, you'd need to do something like...

```
"request": {
    "urlPathPattern": "/publish",
    "method": "POST",
    "headers": {
        "Accept": {
            "matches": "(application\/json|\*\/\*)"
        }
    },
    "bodyPatterns": []
}
```

Comment: Version 2 is what we want to achieve. But the regex is not working. Wiremock still tells the "headers do not match"
Version 1 works,

Comment: What are the exact headers that get passed in? What is the exact error message from WireMock? Is there a closest match result in WireMock?